# How do widgets cover keyboard in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want a widget cover the keyboard in flutter, like the recording button in Telegram.

I've tried some methods, but the widget was cropped by the keyboard.

[image]

Comment: Are you adding your flutter as a modiule or do you have a 100% flutter project?

Comment: I have 100% flutter project.  I didn't want my widget to  be cropped by the keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are building a 100% flutter project I don't think it is possible.
Alternatively you can mix flutter and iOS to achieve this.

Here is why I don't think you can do it only with flutter:

To add something over the keyboard form the iOS side you need to access the windows array and add your custom view over the **last** window, thus making sure it is over the **top most UI** (the keyboard):

```
var customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height-300, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 300))
customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
customView.layer.zPosition = CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)
var windowCount = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.count
UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows[windowCount-1].addSubview(customView);
```

Your "100% flutter" will not have access to the resources described above.

---

In order to have this functionality I would have the the iOS project coordinating the situation a bit.

For example:

Have your flutter implement paths & channels.

Keep your main path for your current flutter implementation.

Add a new path for the view/widget that should be over the keyboard.

On the iOS side should should coordinate with the two flutter instances through channels. Have the iOS side informed when the view/widget should be displayed/removed (and additional stuff if needed, such as, the user tapping on the custom new view/widget).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply! I agree with you. To achieve this, it must rely on native code.

Comment: I am glad to help :)